# int value does not convert correctly to double

Tags: java, double, rounding-error

so I am writing a house class and one of my methods calculates the total area of a house. And then one more method prints of all the details of the house

that is my area method

```
 public double getTotalArea(){
        return ((300 * bedRooms) + familyRoomArea + livingRoomArea );
    }
```

this is my print method

```
 public String toString() {
        return ("House Style =" + this.style + ",bedrooms = " + this.bedRooms +
                ",family room area = " + this.familyRoomArea + ",living room area = "
                + this.livingRoomArea + ",plot = " + this.plot + ", and square feet = " + (double)Math.round(this.getTotalArea() * 100)/100.0);
    }
```

and this is my tester

```
 String style1 = "colonial";
        double familyRoomArea1 = 700;
        double livingRoomArea1 = 500;
        int bedRooms1 = 3;
        double plot1 = 0.7;
        House house1 = new House(style1,familyRoomArea1,livingRoomArea1,bedRooms1,plot1);
        System.out.print("House 1: ");
        System.out.print(house1.toString());
```

this is the current output I get when I run the program

```
House 1: House Style =colonial,bedrooms = 3,family room area = 700.0,living room area = 500.0,plot = 0.7, and square feet = 2100.01
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong here because of the total area I should get 2100.00 but I keep on getting  2100.01 I tried many different things I even used it without the Math.round functions but still, it gives me this answer.

Can I know what might be the issue and how I can fix this please thank you.

Comment: No sir i just check that but I could not find anthing